# C# code is unable to connect to Azure SQL database

Tags: c#, database, azure

I am trying to connect to a sample database I have created in Azure using C# (.NET Core 3.1)
I have enabled my IP address within Azure's Firewall rules.
I am able to use VS2019's SQL Server Object Explorer to connect and view the database within with no problems.

However, when I run a simple C# app on the same PC to execute a query to count the number of records in a table, it throws the following exception at the point where the connection is opened (conn.Open());

*A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The requested address is not valid in its context.)*

The C# code;

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace AzureSql2
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string connStr = " Server=tcp:beaconsqlsql.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=MRP2;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=beaconadmin;Password=********;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;";
      Console.WriteLine("Building connection");
      try
      {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Creating command");
          using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
          {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[Table]";

            Console.WriteLine("Opening connection");
            conn.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("Reading database");
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
              while (reader.Read())
              {
                Console.WriteLine("Record count: {0}", reader.GetInt32(0));
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
      }

      Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit");
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried temporarily turning off the firewall on my PC, but that made no difference.
The fact that SQL Server Object Explorer can connect but the C# code cannot makes it sound like there's a problem with the C# code, but I can't see any differences between it and the samples I've looked at.

Comment: is your table really called "table" ?  Pls share your obfuscated Azure connection string

Comment: Have you read anything like https://mderriey.com/2020/07/17/connect-to-azure-sql-with-aad-and-managed-identities/ ?

Comment: Yes, the table is really called "table" - the database is just a basic experiment with a single table. The error is happening when the connection is first opened, so I would have thought the table name isn't relevant at that point(?). Connection string is: Data Source=beaconsqlsql.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=MRP2;User ID=beaconadmin;Password=********;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False

Comment: I am not sure if this would work, but could you please try changing Data Source to `beaconsqlsql.database.windows.net,1433`? Just adding the port number in there.

Comment: My apologies, some confusion on my behalf.
I have 2 different connection strings.

To initially connect to Azure in SQL Server Explorer, it uses this connection string;
Data Source=beaconsqlsql.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=MRP2;User ID=beaconadmin;Password=********;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False

Comment: To actually connect to the database, the C# code and SQL Server Explorer both are using the connection string provided by Azure;
Server=tcp:beaconsqlsql.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=MRP2;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=beaconadmin;Password=********;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;

Comment: I can hit your Azure server  endpoint (although my IP is rejected as expected). I suspect you have firewall issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created one Azure SQL database and allowed my client IP like below :-

[image]

I created one .Net Console application and ran your code, I replaced

```cs
using System.Data.SqlClient
```

with

```cs
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient
```

You can use any of the above packages.

Copied connection string from Azure Portal > Azure SQL server > Connection string refer below :-

[image]

C# Code:-

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

namespace AzureSql2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connStr = "Server=tcp:sqlservername.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=sqldbname;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=username;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;";
            Console.WriteLine("Building connection");
            try
            {
                using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Creating command");
                    using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Products";

                        Console.WriteLine("Opening connection");
                        conn.Open();

                        Console.WriteLine("Reading database");
                        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Record count: {0}", reader.GetInt32(0));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Output :-

[image]

I tried to run the code with the connection string format you mentioned in the comments :-

```cs
Data Source=azuresqlservername.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=databasename;User ID=siliconuser;Password=password;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False
```

And I was able to run the same code above and got the desired output:-

[image]

When I tried to change the Azure SQL server name in the connection string, I got the same error code as yours, refer below :-

[image]

Verify if your connection string has any syntax missing and validate it from Azure Portal.

Comment: Well, this is weird. I changed the code to use Microsoft.Data.SqlClient (adding the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient NuGet package). That's it - just that one change. And it worked! The app connected and returned a value of 0 for the record count...

Comment: I proceeded to do my happy dance around the room, glad that it finally worked. Then I attempted to run it again. It hasn't worked since then. Back to the same error every time. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Did you check the if the SQL Servername and the entire connection string is correct? And does not miss any syntax or have any extra string added?

Comment: Yes, I've tried with both the connection string as provided by Azure and the version used by SQL Server Explorer. Both give the same error.

Comment: Connection string as copied from Azure    : Server=tcp:beaconsqlsql.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=MRP2;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=beaconadmin;Password={your_password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
Connection string as used by SQL Server Explorer (successfully) : Data Source=beaconsqlsql.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=MRP2;User ID=beaconadmin;Password=********;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False

Comment: beaconsqlsql  'sql' is repeated two times? Is it your Azure SQL server name?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking a copy of the project home and running it on my home PC, and it worked correctly and reliably (after telling Azure to allow that IP address as well)

It turned out the answer was embarrassingly obvious - in addition to the standard Windows 10 firewall, my work PC is running another virus protection/firewall software, and that also needed to be told to allow the app thru.

Definitely one to remember for next time... Although I am kind of intrigued that on two occasions (once mentioned above, once afterwards) out of a few hundred attempts the app did manage to get thru and connect.

Thank you everyone for your answers and help.